# linking cpp object file to c object file and create executable

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++, compiler

Suppose i have a c++ file, created an object file and c file created another object file.
Now i need to link both into one executable. While i'm trying it is giving errors about c++ not found.
Can anyone help me about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should ask this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is is one of the other group..??

Comment: Yes. Just enter here: http://stackoverflow.com/ and login.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two output object files, let's call these files a.o and b.o you can link them into one executable like so:

```
gcc a.o b.o -o output_executable_name
```

Obviously, replace 'output_executable_name' with the name of the program you want to build.
You will need, by default, to have a 'main' function defined in one of those object files and you need to not have any unresolved dependencies with external libraries.

*However*, I want to urge you to perhaps investigate going to a C++/C programming forum as AskUbuntu.com is for solving problems/issues with Ubuntu not for learning C/C++ programming.

I have, as a token of goodwill, attempted to answer your question though - good luck with your programming :)